# Simulate Piezo "knock" Sensor in CircuitLab

Tags: arduino

How can I simulate a Piezo knock sensor in [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/)? I would like to ensure that the circuitry that I have set up to protect the Arduino and divide the voltage is going to work as expected.

I would like to use a voltage signal source to approximate the voltage of a Piezo buzzer after a knock. Specifically, what should I enter as a Fequency for my voltage source (I am going to test with multiple Voltages) and what do I enter in the "Run" screen.

Comment: _how to model a piezo sensor_ and _how to model the mechanical things I'm trying to sense_ are two different questions, and you haven't provided much information on what sensor you are using, or what you are trying to sense. You won't get very specific answers until you do.

Comment: After spending more time with CircuitLab I don't think this is even possible. I don't see any way to vary the Amplitude of my voltage source over time.

Comment: What about "Voltage Function Generator", under "Signal Sources"?

Comment: I'm using the Voltage Function Generator, the problem is making the amplitude of the voltage source start at 50V and drop to zero.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a question about using the voltage function generator in circuitlab.

Comment: @PhilFrost I don't require the answer to use a Voltage function generator. Perhaps there is a way to achieve my goal by combining multiple elements.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to avoid it? It is, in every reasonable situation I can imagine, the right tool for this job. If you don't understand how to use it, you really should ask another question, rather than continuing a discussion in comments.

Comment: @Kelly You can use a normal voltage source and define its voltage algebraically like "SIN(2*PI*1000*T)*EXP(-T/1.0e-2)" [see example](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/a23g29/behavioral-source-exponential-envelope-decay/)

Answer (score 1):

A first approximation of a piezo sensor is a voltage source in series with a very high resistance, say \$10 M\Omega\$. They also tend to have significant mechanical resonances that can be modeled electronically, but doing so is not trivial and is specific to the geometry of a particular sensor. Sensitivity, and consequently the amplitude of the voltage, also varies based on the device and application.